# Reading Java book for .NET programming

Tags: c#, java, .net, clr

It was suggested that Effective Java is a great book to read before programming in C#. What gotchas should I be aware of since the book is not targeted for the .NET environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Effective Java*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) will help you learn good some software development practices but it won't help you with anything specifically related to .NET.  It is a great book and there is much that can be learned by reading it regardless of your language of choice.

If you are looking to polish your C# code then you will probably be better off reading Bill Wagner's [More Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321485890).

That being said, Joshua Bloch is a *very* smart individual and I would recommend his book to any developer.  Also he is a fantastic speaker and many of his presentations can be found on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read a book specifically for c# 3.0 if that is the language you plan to target?

Answer (score 0):

Reading books opens your mind to ideas no matter what language they use to show their examples. Having said that you should at least read another more C# focused book to learn how certain ideas are implemented in your language of choice.